# Citation not shown in pdf

Tags: biblatex, biber

I have some troubles with citations and biber. I'm citing a paper several times and point to different sections in that paper. But sometimes the citation is not shown in the pdf. I can't comprehend when they are not shown. In one section they are shown properly, and in the other section simply a space appears.

First I use

```
\cite{Shani2011}
```

and the second time I use the same (copy and paste)

```
\cite{Shani2011}
```

Inside the Bib reference, the paper is also shown properly. I got no errors in my console, just a few `Overfull \hbox...` and `!h float specifier changed to !ht` warnings, and one `No backend specified, using Biber backend`. I don't know why this biber warning occurs, my command to compile in texmaker is (% references the current document name):

```
"/usr/texbin/pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|
"/usr/texbin/biber" %|
"/usr/texbin/pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|
"/usr/texbin/pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|
open %.pdf
```

Does anyone know where I can start to debug this?

**==========================================**

**EDIT**

Ok, here is a minimum example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago} 

\bibliography{Bibliography2}

\begin{document}
    \cite{Shani2011} blabla. \cite{Shani2011} blabla
\end{document}
```

This produces

```
Shani und Gunawardana 2011 blabla.  blabla
```

The second citation doesn't gets printed into the pdf. But I found out, if I cite between the two Shani2011 another paper, it works. This

```
\begin{document}
    \cite{Shani2011} blabla. \cite{Shani2009} blabla \cite{Shani2011} blabla
\end{document}
```

produces this

```
Shani und Gunawardana 2011 blabla. Shani 2009 blabla Shani und Gun- awardana 2011 blabla
```

So I don't know why this doesn't work. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Here is the Bibliography2.bib:

```
@article{Shani2011,
author = {Shani, Guy and Gunawardana, Asela},
title = {{Evaluating recommendation systems}},
year = {2011}
}

@article{Shani2009,
author = {Shani},
title = {{Evaluating recommendation systems}},
year = {2011}
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is the content of the Masterthsis.blg:

```
[1] Config.pm:361> INFO - This is Biber 1.5
[302] Config.pm:364> INFO - Logfile is 'Masterthesis.blg'
[1209] biber-darwin:193> INFO - === Tue Mar  5, 2013, 10:19:55
[1210] Biber.pm:327> INFO - Reading 'Masterthesis.bcf'
[1426] Biber.pm:619> INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
[1841] Biber.pm:2976> INFO - Processing section 0
[2305] Biber.pm:3086> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'Bibliography2.bib' for section 0
[2449] bibtex.pm:764> INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'Bibliography2.bib'
[4823] Biber.pm:2860> INFO - Overriding locale 'en_US.UTF-8' default tailoring 'level = 4' with 'level = 2'
[4823] Biber.pm:2860> INFO - Overriding locale 'en_US.UTF-8' default tailoring 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
[4823] Biber.pm:2866> INFO - Sorting 'entry' list 'nyt' keys
[4824] Biber.pm:2870> INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'en_US.UTF-8'
[5115] bbl.pm:462> INFO - Writing 'Masterthesis.bbl' with encoding 'ascii'
[5116] bbl.pm:535> INFO - Output to Masterthesis.bbl
```

Comment: Please provide us with a minimal working example (MWE). Take a look at http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html if you are in doubt.

Comment: The "Biber backend" warning is normal if you don't specify a `backend=` argument when loading biblatex. It's there since version 2.0 because before that, bibtex was the default backend. You can ignore it or just add `backend=biber` as an option when you load biblatex.

Comment: Thx for your comments, I added a minimal working example. Hope this helps.

Comment: When using `biblatex`, you don't use `\bibliography{...}`, but `\addbibresource{...}`.

Comment: This example could use a sample bib file; I can't reproduce this issue with biblatex-chicago 0.9.9b. @mafp Use of `\bibliography` is deprecated but otherwise harmless.

Comment: @Audrey I added my Bibliography2.bib file.@mafp thx for the hint, I'll use that cmd from now on, but unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Is there a `.blg` file in the directory? What's its contents?

Comment: I've added the content of the `.blg` file

Comment: @23tux I get the expected result, with a warning that disappears if I use `\textcite` instead of `\cite`.

Comment: I have no problem with your example - it shows both citations. I suspect it's something to do with an outdated biblatex-chicago style (I suspect it's a style issue anyway - not biber related).

Comment: why was this question closed? according to this: http://libguides.radford.edu/chicagostyle two citations of the same source following each other you do NOT print the whole citation again, instead you simply write "Ibid". maybe this is the cause for the second citation not beeing shown? but it seems to be a bug that it does not print "Ibid".

Comment: and now i found the solution to the question! according to the biblatex-chicago documentation http://www.tug.org/texlive//Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/biblatex-chicago/biblatex-chicago.pdf the option noibid disables this behaviour and all citations are fully displayed. use it like this: \usepackage[noibid]{biblatex-chicago} Please reopen the question so i can post this as answer.

Comment: I can't reopen the question, it was closed by others and I don't have enough reputation :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, 'cause @PLK pointed me to the right direction. It seems that an outdated biblatex-chicago package caused the problem. I thought I updated everything to the latest versions, but my package manager on OS X, Tex Live Utility, just updates partial. So I had to re-run the update process a several times (and Tex Live found after every update new versions), now it's fixed. May this helps somebody else.

Comment: i've updated tex-live 2012 to the latest version but i still have that problem. what version of biblatex-chicago do you have?

Comment: 0.9.9b is my biblatex-chicago version

Comment: the correct solution can be found in the comments of the question